# Create single-property indexes on a loop in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to do something like this in cypher?

```
WITH ["John", "Jane"] AS names
FOREACH (name IN names | CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name))
```

If not, is there any APOC alternative to achieve the same?

Thanks!

Note:

I am using `Neo4j 3.5`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?

You can create John and Jane like this (see the [docs on UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/controlling-query-processing/#results-unwind))

```
WITH ['John','Jane'] AS names
UNWIND names AS name
CREATE (p:Person {name:name})
RETURN p
```

But when you create an index, you create an index for a property on all Nodes of that type. So to index "name" you only need (see [docs on INDEX](https://neo4j.com/graphgists/labels-constraints-and-indexes/)):

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)
```

Comment: I am trying to collect a set of property names and then add index on all of them in a dynamic fashion 

```MATCH (p:Person) 
WITH collect(p.name) AS names
FOREACH (name IN names | CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name))```